# Realm - Catch an exception in realm.create

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can I catch an Exception in create method from Realm's framework? I am trying like this but I never catch the Exception about duplicate primary keys.

```
do {
    try! realm.write() {
    let person = realm.create(Person.self, value: ["Jim", 0])
    person.age.value = 30
}

}

catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

The error:

```
realm1[922:26059] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', 
reason: 'Can't set primary key property 'name' to existing value 'Jim'.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do {...} catch {...}` is only for catching Errors that are thrown from swift methods, it is not for catching exceptions.

> The standard Cocoa convention is that exceptions signal programmer error and are not intended to be recovered from.
>   [- LLVM Docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions)

So if an exception is being thrown, it generally means that you are not checking something before an operation. In this case, you should check for a `Person` that already exists with that primary key then update it or create a new `Person` if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: `update: true` can also be passed to `.create()` to update the existing object rather than throwing if an object with that PK already exists.

Comment: This crucial difference between catchable errors and non recoverable programmer exceptions should be much better documented IMHO.